# android regex that contains at least 3 type of characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I want a regex on android that contains at least 3 type of characters from this type :

```
Number, upper letter, lower letter and special characters,
```

i found this regex

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,100}
```

But this tells Minimum 8 and Maximum, 10 characters, at-least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character. 
but i need 3 types from this 4 types, not all 4 types.

For example this passwords is valid :

Test1987   (because it contains 3 type = upper character, lower, and digit)
&est7sss  (valid too it contains special character, digit, and lower characters)

Password not valid :

test1987  (contains only two type lower and digit)

How can i do that please

-----------------EDIT-------------

I used a fonction like this and it seems to work

```
   public boolean validatePassword(final String password){
      Integer numberType = 0;
      if(password.length() > 7){

      if (password.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
          numberType = numberType + 1;
      }
      if (password.matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
          numberType = numberType + 1;
      }
      if (password.matches(".*[A-Z].*")) {
          numberType = numberType + 1;
      }
      if (!password.matches("[A-Za-z0-9 ]*")) {
          numberType = numberType + 1;
      }
      }
      else{
          return false;

      }

      if(numberType>2)
          return true;
      return false;

  }
```

Comment: i would like to ask for clarifications and try to be more specific about which types you are talking about?

Comment: i just edit my question with example, can you read it please and tell me if it is more clear ?

Comment: Pure regex solution for this would be ugly. Better you handle this in code.

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s19.html search for text `3 out of 4`

Answer (score 1):

```
  public boolean validatePassword(final String password){
      Integer numberType = 0;
      if(password.length() > 7){

      if (password.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
          numberType = numberType + 1;
      }
      if (password.matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
          numberType = numberType + 1;
      }
      if (password.matches(".*[A-Z].*")) {
          numberType = numberType + 1;
      }
      if (!password.matches("[A-Za-z0-9 ]*")) {
          numberType = numberType + 1;
      }
      }
      else{
          return false;

      }

      if(numberType>2)
          return true;
      return false;

  }
```

Comment: dont u need less than 100 condition as well